# My Debian 12 keeps raising "eth0" interface when it doesn't exist

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ethernet

I'm new to Debian and Linux in general and I have a curious problem I have no idea how to fix. I'm on Debian Testing (currently bookworm).

During boot, my Debian always says that it fails to raise network interface and that I should check my networking service for more information. When I check the log with `sudo journalctl -u networking.service`, I found the following messages:

```
ifup[861]: Cannot find device "eth0"
dhclient[851]: Failed to get interface index: No such device
ifup[851]: Failed to get interface index: No such device
ifup[851]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
ifup[851]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
ifup[851]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
ifup[851]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
ifup[851]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
ifup[851]: exiting.
dhclient[851]: 
dhclient[851]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
dhclient[851]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
dhclient[851]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
dhclient[851]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
dhclient[851]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
dhclient[851]: 
dhclient[851]: exiting.
ifup[784]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

I think this is the cause of my issue because my Ethernet interface is called `enp3s0`. not `eth0`, and `ifup` tries to raise a network interface that doesn't exist.

However, I have no idea why it is looking for `eth0`. My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is as follows; you can see it doesn't mention `eth0` anywhere, only `lo`, `wlp2s0` (wifi) and `enp3s0`.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.39
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
 wpa-ssid "***"
 wpa-psk "***"

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.39
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: is `enp3s0` OK? try `sudo grep -rl eth0 /etc` - any hits?

Comment: There are actually several hits: /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf, 
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf, /etc/samba/smb.conf, /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf, /etc/minidlna.conf.

Comment: I looked into each conf files above but the lines with `eth0` seem to be all commented out. Let me know if I should check for anything in particular.

Comment: Make sure `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` is correct and and if it's not rebuild your `initrd`.

Comment: Debian is weird. In Fedora 37 I have eth0 only as a commented out string in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to check if `initramfs.conf` is correct - any line I have to pay attention to? The only line in `initramfs.conf` with the word `eth0` is a comment/documentation line that says `# Specify a specific network interface, like eth0`, but the value of the actual variable itself isn't set to anything.

Comment: Ah, OK. No idea then. Sorry.

Comment: you didn't answer my first question. Is `enp3s0` OK? i.e. up and connected?

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, it's up and connected.

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`?

Comment: @telcoM There's a file named `setup`. The content of the file is currently exactly the same as the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: Are you running NetworkManager? Does `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory have any files in it? Also, normally `/run/network/` should be on `tmpfs`: if it is on a persistent filesystem for some reason, there might be an obsolete `ifstate*` file lurking around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how I fixed it, but I've fixed it. Below are what I've tried today (that finally fixed the issue) for future references.
**Some of these are probably unrelated and I can't guarantee if it won't break anything if someone tries what I did**. I backed up my data and tried whatever solutions I found online.

1. Removed `connman` (`sudo apt remove connman`). After I did this, my network was broken. I think it couldn't connect to any DNS servers except the default one (192.168.1.1, my router) and seemed to only be able to connect a few sites (like Reddit and Google). I tried to ping several other sites and got "Network is unreachable" errors.
2. Logged into my router web config (192.168.1.1 in my case), removed and re-added my enp3s0 interface's MAC address in the MAC-Based Static IP Assignment table, mapping it to 192.168.1.39.
3. Removed `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` file (the one with the same content as `/etc/network/interfaces`) after reading [a Debian User Forums thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20230130124100/https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=149596)
4. Restarted enp3s0 with `sudo ifconfig enp3s0 down` and then `sudo ifconfig enp3s0 up`. Upon running the latter command, I got `RLNETLINK: File exists` error. I tried following Ébe Isaac's answer in this [Raspberry Pi thread](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/solving-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-running-ifup) and run `sudo ip addr flush dev enp3s0` before bringing up the interface successfully.
5. Commented out the duplicate network gateway line of `wlp2s0` in my `/etc/network/interfaces/` following theo-brown's answer in the same thread. Restarted router and laptop. The network is no longer broken and the boot error message is also gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a debian-like parrot os operating system. The other day after the update, my network disappeared, after some dancing with a tambourine, I realized that the RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver was blacklisted.
I commented out the lines in file `/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf`:

```
#alias  pci:v00001186d00004300sv00001186sd00004B10bc*sc*i*  r8168 
    
#alias  pci:v000010ECd00008168sv*sd*bc*sc*i*            r8168
```

then run these commands as root:

```bash
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

Then network is OK.